# Pagination for Custom Post Types using Shortcode not showing

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

At first, I have already checked similar questions, but none of the solutions  is solving my issue.

So, I've the below codes, its generating the posts when I use the shortcode. But pagination/navigation is not showing. Here is the code -

```
add_shortcode( 'wm-offers', 'shortcodes_offers' );
function shortcodes_offers( $atts ) {
    // define attributes and their defaults
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'items_per_row' => '2',
        'posts' => 10,
    ), $atts ) );

    // define query parameters based on attributes
    $options = array(
        'post_type' => 'offers',
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
    );

    $grid_col = (12 / $items_per_row);

    $query = new WP_Query( $options );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <div class="row ">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-<?php echo $grid_col;?>">
                <div class="card wm-coupons-post-card">
                    <?php
                        echo '<div class="card-img">';
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('wm-post-thumb');
                            } else {
                                echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/content-cards-placeholder.png"  />';
                            }
                            echo '<div class="post-date">';
                                echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'offer_expire', true ) );
                            echo '</div>';

                            echo '<div class="post-categories">';
                                $categories_list = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', 'wm-coupons' ) );
                                if ( $categories_list && wm_coupons_categorized_blog() ) {
                                    printf( '' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'wm-coupons' ) . '', $categories_list ); // WPCS: XSS OK.'<span class="fa fa-tags"></span> ' . 
                                }
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>  
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">
                            <?php
                                echo '<span class="fa fa-user"></span> <a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a>';

                                edit_post_link($link = '<span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Edit', $before = '', $after = '', $id = "", $class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary ml-1");
                            ?>
                        </h6> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <?php
                            the_excerpt(); 
                        ?>

                        <p class="text-xs-right mb-0">
                            <?php 
                                echo get_the_tag_list(' ', ' ') . ' <span class="fa fa-tags"></span>';
                            ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-footer text-xs-right">
                        <?php
                            if ( ! is_single() && ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) {
                                echo '<span class="comments-link pull-left"><span class="fa fa-comment-o"></span> ';

                                comments_popup_link( sprintf( wp_kses( __( 'Leave a Comment', 'wm-coupons' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => array() ) ) ) ) );
                                echo '</span>';
                            }

                            echo ' <a class="read-more btn btn-sm btn-info" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Read More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) ?></div>
        <?php 
            the_posts_pagination();
            wp_reset_postdata(); 
        ?>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does $posts get its value because you say 'posts_per_page' => $posts, but where is posts defined?

Comment: @ArberBraja look at line 6.

Comment: Hi Xahed, did my answer help you out?

Comment: I found a solution somewhere else. But it was same as yours. So marked yours as answer so other get the solution if they face same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code contains two errors;

- The `get_next_posts_link` and `get_previous_posts_link` functions should be echoed. So e.g. `echo get_next_post_link(...)`.
- Your `WP_Query` should use the `paged` parameter.

More information about the `paged` parameter can be found in the WordPress Codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). An example of using pagination in a custom loop can be seen [here](http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination).

Good luck!